# NetworkConfiguration cause web roles to recycle

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

Adding NetworkConfiguration to ServiceConfiguration cause our web roles to recycle:

-Busy (Waiting for role to start... System startup tasks are running

-Restarting (Role has encountered an error and has stopped. System startup task failed with exit code -532462766

Without NetworkConfiguration everything runs ok. We need roles visibility to a SQL VM in the same azure virtual network (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj823135.aspx).

```
  <NetworkConfiguration>
    <Dns>
      <DnsServers>
        <DnsServer name="TestDNS" IPAddress="10.1.0.4" />
      </DnsServers>
    </Dns>
    <VirtualNetworkSite name="TestNetWork" />
    <AddressAssignments>
      <InstanceAddress roleName="Role1">
        <Subnets>
          <Subnet name="TestSubnet" />
        </Subnets>
      </InstanceAddress>
      <InstanceAddress roleName="Role2">
        <Subnets>
          <Subnet name="TestSubnet" />
        </Subnets>
      </InstanceAddress>
      <InstanceAddress roleName="Role3">
        <Subnets>
          <Subnet name="TestSubnet" />
        </Subnets>
      </InstanceAddress>
    </AddressAssignments>
  </NetworkConfiguration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

We have set an Affinity Group, and the Cloud Service within.

If you depend on a other service outside the Affinity Group (for ex storage, virtual network, cache, etc) the roles won't start.